# Anti-Invariant Polynomials of the Dihedral group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, classical-invariant-theory

I'm interested in the one-dimensional irreducible representations of $D_{2n}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. I have found that the trivial representations for an algebra freely generated by $x^2+y^2$ and $Re[(x+i y)^n]$. This is great, but the other representation I really need is the sign representation, (possibly called an Anti-Invariant polynomial), for which I can only think of $Im[(x+iy)^n]$, and even that only works for $n$ odd.

So I guess my question is: If I want a polynomial invariant under rotation by $2\pi/n$ and odd in $y$, must it be so that $n$ is odd and my polynomial is a multiple of $Im[(x+iy)^n]$?

References would be appreciated!

Comment: But $Im[(x+iy)^n]$ is mapped to $-Im[(x+iy)^n]$ by the reflection $x\mapsto x, y\mapsto -y$ for any $n$. So that gives you the sign representation.